# Centering a .jpg image in PDF using Imagemagick?

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, jpeg, center

I'm using `convert` version ImageMagick 6.6.2-6 2011-03-16, and I'd like to use it to generate an A4 pdf from an image, where the image will be non-scaled and centered.

I'm running the following (as a modification of [Overlaying Images with ImageMagick](http://www.randomsequence.com/articles/overlaying-images-with-imagemagick/)):

```
# generate a 100x100 JPG with just red color
convert -size 100x100 xc:red red.jpg

# generate PDF from JPG
convert -page A4 xc:white red.jpg -gravity center -composite -format pdf out.pdf
```

... but, basically nothing shows? Same thing happens for a png image...

Note that

- Just '`convert -page A4 red.jpg out.pdf`' works - but the image is not centered; (*`-gravity center` causes image not to show*)
- If the image is png, '`convert -page A4 -gravity center red.png out.pdf`' does indeed work fine

... however, I'd like `convert` to embed the contents of the JPEG stream directly - hence, I wouldn't like to convert the JPG to PNG first.

So, would it be possible to use `convert` to center a JPG image in an A4 PDF page directly?

Many thanks in advance for any answers,
Cheers!

EDIT2: @John Keyes answer works for the example above; where the image is "smaller" than the PDF size -- however if the image is bigger, e.g.:

```
$ convert -size 1228x1706 -background \#f44 -rotate 45 gradient:\#f00-\#fff red.jpg
$ identify red.jpg 
red.jpg JPEG 2075x2075 2075x2075+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 120KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

... then it will fail. However, it turns out: "[if you change -extent to 50x50, then play with -gravity, you'll see changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306045/imagemagick-gravity-parameter/2306210#2306210)" - except, the question is: *which* extent do you change, that of the image - or that of the final PDF?

Well, it turns out - it is the extent of the final PDF... To find that size as `convert` sees it, check the page: [Magick::Geometry](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Geometry.html) - however, note that the "Postscript page size specifications" like "`A4+43+43>`" unfortunately, cause `convert` to crash in this context... But at least the respective numbers for the size (595x842) can be copied from the page; and finally this works:

```
convert -page A4 -gravity center -resize 595x842 -extent 595x842 red.jpg out.pdf
```

... and actually, the `-extent` part is not really needed - the `-resize` part is the important one to have the large image show..

However, the problem here is that the image included seems to be resampled - however, I'd just like to show it scaled so it fits the page, but would otherwise like the original JPG stream to be inserted in the file.. So I guess the question is still partially open :)

EDIT: Related:

- [ImageMagick Gravity parameter - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306045/imagemagick-gravity-parameter)
- [ImageMagick and Geometry Issue - resizing with > - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441720/imagemagick-and-geometry-issue-resizing-with)
- [command line - Resizing and croping images to an aspect ratio of 6x4 with width of 1024 pixels - Unix and Linux - Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11974/resizing-and-croping-images-to-an-aspect-ratio-of-6x4-with-width-of-1024-pixels)
- [conversion - using imagemagick or ghostscript (or something) to scale PDF to fit page? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547326/using-imagemagick-or-ghostscript-or-something-to-scale-pdf-to-fit-page)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following works perfectly for me:

```
convert -page A4 red.jpg  -gravity center -format pdf out.pdf
```

and if you change the order of the "files" it works too:

```
convert -page A4 red.jpg xc:white -gravity center -composite -format pdf out.pdf
```

I think the red.jpg is centered but the white is drawn on top of it.

Comment: Awesome - many thanks, @John Keyes! I could have sworn I had already tried something with `-format pdf` and I failed; but I'm trying yer first command line and it works great! :) Thanks again - cheers!

Comment: You're welcome. I've gone down the rabbit hole of ImageMagick options many times.

Comment: This does not work for large images (Version 6.9.2) , in my case converting 5 MByte JPEG. It just produces a blank page. Without the "gravity center" option it works, but is not centered, of course. Seems to be an open issue: https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=22759

Comment: Both of these put the red square on top left corner for me, even though it says `-gravity center`...

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is outside of imagemagick, but here is a solution in Latex, using `tikz` package (using [How to define a figure size so that it consumes the rest of a page? #14514](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14512/how-to-define-a-figure-size-so-that-it-consumes-the-rest-of-a-page/14514#14514)), which seems to reliably place images on page, and preserve them fully:

```
% note: need to run pdflatex twice!! First time generates blank pages!
% convert -size 1228x1706 -background \#f44 -rotate 45 gradient:\#f00-\#fff red.jpg
% convert -size 595x1400 xc:red redlong.jpg

\documentclass[a4paper]{letter}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[hmargin=0.5cm,vmargin=0.5cm]{geometry} % sets page margins

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\imagepage}[1]{
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]\coordinate (image-start); \par
\vfill
\null\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \path let \p0 = (0,0), \p1 = (image-start) in
    node [inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,anchor=center] at (current page.center) {%
      \pgfmathsetmacro\imgheight{\y1-\y0}%
      \includegraphics[height=\imgheight pt,width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{#1}%
  };
\end{tikzpicture}%
}



\begin{document}


% there must be a \n\n after {letter!}
\begin{letter}

  \imagepage{red.jpg}
\end{letter}


\begin{letter}

  \imagepage{redlong.jpg}
\end{letter}

% see also \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\includegraphics{red.jpg}}
\end{document}
```

Note, the `letter` documentclass is used to allow that each image is split on separate page..